# Generic parameter T not implicitly assignable to object -- generic method calling nongeneric overloaded method

Tags: c#, generics, casting, overloading

Why is `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` is not assignable to parameter type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>`, given that `object` is C# ultimate base class?

---

I stumbled upon this curiosity when doing something similar to the following code. It's a generic method calling an overloaded non-generic method.

```cs
void Main()
{
    List<object> objects = new List<object>();

    Method(objects); // This calls the method with IEnumerable, as expected

    MethodCaller(objects); 
}

void MethodCaller<T> (IEnumerable<T> objects) 
{
    Method(objects); // Calls method overload 2, with object as parameter - why?

    // Why is the following line required to call the method overload 1? 
    // Can't C# do this automatically, given that object is the ultimate base class for everything?
    IEnumerable<object> casted = (IEnumerable<object>) objects; 
    Method(casted); // Calls method overload 1
}

void Method (IEnumerable<object> param) 
{
    // Method overload 1
    Console.WriteLine("Method overload 1 - with IEnumerable<object> as parameter");
}

void Method (object param) 
{
    // Method overload 2
    Console.WriteLine("Method overload 2 - with object as parameter");
}
```

I don't understand why the generic method should not be calling the first overload instead of the second. I thought that the compiler should be able to say that any `<T>` can be implicitly cast to `object`, therefore `IEnumerable<T>` should be implicitly castable to `IEnumerable<object>`.

In other words:

```cs
IEnumerable<object> casted = (IEnumerable<object>) objects;
```

Why is this line required to call the method overload 1? Can't C# do that automatically, given that object is the ultimate base class?

Is it because C# assumes that I might be passing a `<T>` which is not compatible with the type `object` -- even though everything is actually `object`?

Comment: *"I know that generics are bound at Runtime"* -- You do? Anyway, change the second method signature to `static void Method<T>(IEnumerable<T> param)`

Comment: IEnumerable<object> is not a super class of IEnumerable<T> (whatever T is). You can't assign the second to a variable of the first type as they are considered to be completely different.

Comment: Because, according to the compiler, *"Argument type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` is not assignable to parameter type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>`"* (and this decision is made at design time, not rutime).

Comment: The point is that overload resolution is not done at runtime. It's done at compile time. The compiler isn't going to set up MethodCaller so it can call different overloads depending on what got passed in (unless you pass in `dynamic`, but don't). The overload it calls is the overload that makes sense with the information it has right there in that method. Give it an option that takes the type parameter into account, and it'll work with you.

Comment: s/second method signature/first method signature/ -- i had them reversed in my copy

Comment: Thanks to SteveTodd and @RufusL for rightly pointing those things out. I've updated the question to better reflect my doubt.

Comment: @alexlomba87 Try `MethodCaller(new int[0]);`

Comment: Thanks @PetSerAl but I'm not trying to "solve" my code; rather I'm looking for a sort of answer like Motti's below.

Comment: @alexlomba87 I am not "solving" your code, but crashing it.

Comment: @SteveTodd: IEnumerable<object>` is a supertype of `IEnumerable<anyClassType`, but is not a supertype of any generic of the form `IEnumerable<someParticularValueType>`.

Comment: @supercat not sure I follow. You can always do `IEnumerable<int> ienumOfInts = null;` and then `IEnumerable<object> ienumOfObjects = (IEnumerable<object>)ienumOfInts;`

Comment: @alexlomba87: See Jon Skeet's answer.

Comment: @alexlomba87: You can do that, and for a null reference it will succeed, but if you use `IEnumerable<int> ienumOfInts = new List<int>();` instead, it will fail at execution time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's take overload resolution out of the equation here. This is about [*generic variance*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance). In particular, you're expecting there to be an implicit conversion from `IEnumerable<T>` to `IEnumerable<object>`.

That doesn't work, because generic variance only works when the type arguments are known to be reference types. From the linked documentation:

> Variance applies only to reference types; if you specify a value type for a variant type parameter, that type parameter is invariant for the resulting constructed type.

So for example, this is fine:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = ...;
IEnumerable<object> objects = strings;
```

But this fails:

```
IEnumerable<int> ints = ...;
IEnumerable<object> objects = ints;
```

In your generic case, `T` could be any type *including a value type*. That's why it fails. If you constrain `T` to be a reference type using the `where T : class` constraint, it's fine.

So to be concrete, this is invalid:

```
static void Foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> ts)
{
    IEnumerable<object> objects = ts;
}
```

But this is valid:

```
static void Foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> ts) where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<object> objects = ts;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, clear and concise. I especially like the fact you included the `where` part in the answer. I'm only left with the curiosity about why generic variance is constrained to reference types only.

Comment: @alexlomba87: It's a CLR restriction at its heart - basically because the representation of every reference is the same, so the CLR doesn't need to care at execution time... every reference value is the same size, etc. I'm sure one of Eric's blog posts covers this in more detail: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/covariance-and-contravariance/

Answer (score -2):

IEnumerable< object> is not a super class of IEnumerable< T> (whatever T is). You can't assign the second to a variable of the first type as they are considered to be completely different. You need to cast the type of your IEnumerable to object before you will get a matching signature like:

```
void MethodCaller<T> (IEnumerable<T> objects) 
{
    Method(objects.Cast<object>()); 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs question at all, the OPs question is "why is this this way?" not "How do I make this work?" Beyond that, if you are going to use Linq you could just use `objects.Cast<object>()` instead.

Comment: I told him why his code wouldn't work as expected in the comments to the question. I can repeat the reasoning in the answer if you wish (and yes, your way is a little neater).